# Python typing signature for instance of subclass?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Consider:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

class A:
    @classmethod
    def get(cls) -> A:
        return cls()

class B(A):
    pass

def func() -> B: # Line 12
    return B.get()
```

Running mypy on this we get:

```
$ mypy test.py
test.py:12: error: Incompatible return value type (got "A", expected "B")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Additionally, I have checked to see if old-style recursive annotations work. That is:

```py
# from __future__ import annotations

class A:
    @classmethod
    def get(cls) -> "A":
# ...
```

...to no avail.

Of course one could do:

```py
from typing import cast

def func() -> B: # Line 12
    return cast(B, B.get())
```

Every time this case pops up. But I would like to avoid doing that.

How should one go about typing this?

Comment: I'm unsure about what you're asking. If you want to return `A`, you need to cast it explicitely. If you just want to type-annotate your function correctly, why not `def func() -> A`?

Comment: I actually want to return `B` in `func`. For example, suppose we have classes representing database entities. We have a common class `Entity` and subclasses like `User` and `Project`. These subclasses also have additional, idiosyncratic attributes that matter. We want to be explicit about whether your returning a `User` or `Project` because that will constrain what we can do downstream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cls` and `self` parameters are usually inferred by `mpyp` to avoid a lot of redundant code, but when required they can be specified explicitly by annotations.

In this case the explicit type for the class method would look like the following:

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def get(cls: Type[A]) -> A:
        return cls()
```

So what we really need here is a way to make `Type[A]` a generic parameter, such that when the class method is called from a child class, you can reference the child class instead. Luckily, we have `TypeVar` values for this.

Working this into your existing example we will get the following:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TypeVar, Type


T = TypeVar('T')


class A:
    @classmethod
    def get(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
        return cls()


class B(A):
    pass


def func() -> B:
    return B.get()
```

Now `mypy` should be your friend again!