# Annotating "Instance of a subclass derived from specific base class"

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a Python method with the following signature:

```py
def basic_sizer(self, ctrl):
```

where `ctrl` can be any wxPython control derived from `wx.Control`. Is there a specific Python stock annotation to indicate this other than either

```py
def basic_sizer(self, ctrl: wx.Control):
```

or

```py
def basic_sizer(self, ctrl: Union[wx.SpinCtrl, wx.BitmapButton, <other possible controls>]):
```

I have tried

```py
def basic_sizer(self, ctrl: Type[wx.Control]):
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65963177/python-typing-signature-for-instance-of-subclass). This approach is also presented in the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type), but PyCharm does not accept it, flagging mismatched type. I do not want to use some PyCharm-specific hack, even if available. Rather, I am interested in whether the Python *typing* module provides a generic approach for this situation.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link just provided. I think this is what you want: [Type hint for return value in subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282879/type-hint-for-return-value-in-subclass).

Comment: No, I do not see how this is relevant. I do not have any complications of sorts. I can use Union[<subclass list>] just fine. The problem is that I do not want to lock my function to specific subclasses when the function should accept any subclass. Both the base class and derived classes are part of a third party library. I am not trying to reference the base class within its subclass or something like it.

Comment: Is the `ctrl` argument an *instance* of the class you're describing, or the class object itself? Is there any reason that just annotating with the base class (as in your second code block) can't work?

Comment: ctrl is an INSTANCE as indicated in both title and examples (except for the last one). I have not checked whether PyCharm accepts the base class annotation, but, even if it does, this annotation is inaccurate. When someone reads the code and sees the base-class annotation, it is not obvious, that the function also expects instances of subclasses. In fact, there might be scenarios when I may not be willing to accept instances of the base class.

Comment: I think your two options are to enumerate the subclasses you *will* accept, or define a new (abstract) subclass of `wx.Control` to use as the base class for the classes you do want to accept (which itself is a form of indirect enumeration).

Comment: If you can't accept instances of the base class, that implies some extra behavior that must be present in the subclasses; that's typically modeled using a specific subclass of `wx.Control` to inherit from. Depending on that behavior, you might be able to define a `Protocol` to represent the subset of subclasses that you can accept.

Answer (score -1):

### Abstraction

You have some base class `SomeBase`. You want to write and annotate a function `foo` that takes an argument `arg`. That argument `arg` can be an instance of `SomeBase` or of any subclass of `SomeBase`. This is how you write that:

```py
def foo(arg: SomeBase):
    ...
```

Say now there are classes `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` that both inherit from `SomeBase` and you realize that `arg` should actually only ever be an instance of *any of those* subclasses and *not* be of the type `SomeBase` (directly). Here is how you write that:

```py
def foo(arg: DerivedA | DerivedB):
    ...
```

Or in Python `<3.10`:

```py
from typing import Union

def foo(arg: Union[DerivedA, DerivedB]):
    ...
```

To my knowledge, there is currently no way to annotate that `arg` should be an instance of *any* subclass of `SomeBase` *but not* of the class `SomeBase` itself.

---

### Concrete

I am not familiar with `wxPython`, but you stated that you want the argument `ctrl` to

> be any wxPython control derived from `wx.Control`.

According to the documentation, [`wx.Control`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Control.html?highlight=control#wx.Control) is in fact a class. Your statement is still ambiguous in whether or not the `ctrl` argument should be assumed to be *any* instance of `wx.Control`. But if so, you do write:

```py
def basic_sizer(self, ctrl: wx.Control):
    ...
```

If you want to restrict it to specific subclasses, you use the `Union`.

But this is wrong:

```py
def basic_sizer(self, ctrl: Type[wx.Control]):
    ...
```

That would state that `ctrl` must be a **class** (as opposed to an *instance* of a class), namely `wx.Control` or any subclass of it. Unless of course that *is in fact* what you want... Again, your statement is ambiguous.

---

### Mismatched types

Possible reasons for PyCharm complaining about "mismatched types" include:

- You are calling the method `basic_sizer` providing an argument for `ctrl` that is **not** actually an instance of `wx.Control`.
- `wxPython` messed up big time in their typing.
- PyCharm has a bug in its static type checker.

If you provide the code that produces the PyCharm complaint and the specific message by PyCharm, we can sort this out.

**PS:**

If the PyCharm complaint arises in some other place because you assume that `ctrl` has certain attributes that it may not have, that would probably indicate that you actually need it to be an instance of *specific* subclasses. There are multiple ways to handle this, depending on the situation.